# Expected amount of wins in a set of games

Tags: probability

I'm just trying to wrap my head around the application of some basic probability.

Assume a set consists of 6 games, and the probability of winning each game is 0.6. Furthermore, a set is considered won if 4 or more games are won. I'm trying to calculate the following

- What is the expected number of games won in the next set?
- What is the probability of winning the next set?

I believe the expected number can be calculated via (0.6 * 6) but I'm not sure how to calculate the probability of winning the set.

Comment: Do you make any assumptions on the independence between the winning probability between games? If they are independent, can you find the probability for one to win 6 out of 6 games? How about 5 out of 6 games and 4 out of 6 games?

Answer (score 0):

The probability of winning the next set is the probability of winning atleast 4 of the 6 games. So that would mean using the binomial distribution to calculate the probability of winning 4, 5 and 6 games and summing them up together.